# react triggers onclick when component is mounted

Tags: reactjs

I am passing a component to a nested component a `onClick` method that modifies the state of the parent component.

Somehow the method is being called when a component (not sure if it's parent or child) is being mounted. And now, I'm getting the following error message:

> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: setState(...): Cannot update
>   during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render
>   methods should be a pure function of props and state.invariant

The code for passing the child looks like the following

```jsx
    var playlists = this.props.data.map(function(playlist) {
      return (
        <PlaylistItem key={playlist.id}
                      data={playlist}
                      showPlaylistCode={this.getPlaylistCodeData} 
        />
      );
    }.bind(this));
```

Comment: That looks fine. Something else is breaking. We need to see more code.

Comment: @UAvalos I'm not sure which parts of code to show, because I'm not sure what's relevant

Comment: @UAvalos since I wasn't sure, I placed them all here https://gist.github.com/angelathewebdev/31a5e441a3a152dea019

Comment: In line 20 of play list item,  you're actually calling the on click function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Playlist Item component, line 20, try changing it to:

```
<div className="playlistCode i mfi-qr-code" onClick={this.props.showPlaylistCode.bind(this, this.props.data.id)}></div>
```

When you need to send an argument to a function that's used onClick in React, you need to use bind. As with any use of bind(), the first argument should be the context of this, and the second should be what you want to send to the click handler function.